# Dumpout Process Memory Layout During Loading Time

Tags: instrumentation, binary-editing

I am working on a project where I need to use `LD_PRELOAD` to load some libraries into the memory space.

It's like:

```
 LD_PRELOAD="./libapp.so" ./my_app
```

Due to certain reasons (I am actually working on some binary hacking), I must know **the memory address** (not a symbol) of certain functions (let's say, `foo`) in `libapp.so` and instrument the binary code of `my_app` before execution.

However, due to `ASLR` (Address Space Layout Randomization), each time `libapp.so` would be loaded into different memory address, and I am unable to know the memory address of `foo` before execution.

I am thinking to somehow intercept the loading time, readout the memory address of `libapp.so`, perform some instrumentation on `my_app` with the memory address of `foo`, and then load `my_app` into the memory space.

So here is my question: how to intercept the loading process and acquire the memory address of `libapp.so`?

Comment: gdb does have pending bps , solib events break etc does none of them work. bp xxx pending on , set solibevents x,y etc  or do you mean you want to do it standalone  if you are using ptrace apis u should be able to intercept loading events too ala gdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that one option could be to use `ptrace`, for example you can use `_dl_open()` instead of `LD_PRELOAD`. Look at this example:

- http://www.ars-informatica.com/Root/Code/2010_04_18/LinuxPTrace.aspx

Another option could be to use `gdb` for do that, for example you have the possibility to set a pending breakpoint to foo and then run the program.

Another option could be turn off the ASLR, you can do it using the `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`

To disable it you can run:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```